# Real- Valued Random Variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

[image] This is from Ross Ihaka's notes about Time Series Analysis.

> Any random variable which has probability 1 of being zero will have $\langle X,X \rangle = 0$, which violates the requirement that this only happen when $X=0$.

1. How can a real-valued random variable has probability 1 of being zero and probability 0 of being other values?
2. Why is there uniqueness problem here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A random variable is a (measurable) function from a sample space to the real numbers. There is nothing wrong with mapping (almost) everything to value 0. This is still a random variable.

When $X=0$ with probability $1$, $\langle X,X\rangle$ equals to 0.

Here is an example, let the sample space be the interval $[0,1]$ with uniform measure. For a $x$ in the sample space, $X(x) = 0$ for all $x$ in the sample space except $X(0.5)=1$, then $EX^2=0$ but $X$ is not 0 everywhere. This violates uniqueness that there is only one $X$ such that $EX^2=0$

This is quite standard in probability theory: you just treat two r.v. as the same if they equal almost everywhere, i.e. they differ only on a set of measure $0$. You 'quotient' out the equivalent classes of random variables which are the same almost everywhere, then the 0 is unique. This is known as $L^2$ space.

from a practical point of view, just ignore it, it does not matter.

Comment: So in this case, X is not a continuous RV, is it? I thought a real-valued RV had to be a continuous RV. Anyway, I haven't learned about Measure Theory. I guess I have to read some of it.

Comment: @user74158 it is not a continuous function, but there is nothing which says it has to be. measurable is much weaker than continuous, but the r.v. example i gave is actually identical to $X(x)=0$ for all $x$ from a practical point of view because a set of measure 0 does not matter. The reason he mentions it at the end is that $\langle x,x\rangle=0$ if and only if $x=0$ in an inner product space, i.e. $0$ is unique, but if you quotient out all random variables which is almost everywhere the same, you get the uniquness back.

Comment: @user74158 i do not know what you mean by $X$ is a continuous random variable. This is not a concept well defined in probability theory. would you say $X(x)=0$ for all $x$ is a continuous random variable?

Comment: [Continuous RV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_distribution#Continuous_probability_distribution) This is what I mean. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: How do you calculate $EX^2=0$ where $X(x)=0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ except $X(0.5)=1$?

Comment: @user74158 the same way you integrate this function on the interval [0,1]. Note $X^2=0$ everywhere except $X^2(0.5)=1$. you draw a grid and realise when the size of the interval vanishes, so does the contribution from the discontinuity!

Comment: @user74158 A continuous probability distribution is a probability distribution that has a probability density function. it said nothing about $X$ have to be a continuous